# Strategies linebreaking bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex

Modifying the source slightly is is often the shortest path to a good line breaking, even on a Bibliography and entries like

[image: linebreak1]

one can abbreviate the Series, shorthen the publisher to "Springer" and get a good enough output.

Sometimes that becomes almost impossible, like in the example below

[image]

where every value is fixed and cannot be shortened or enlarged in any way.

Introducing an "artificial" linebreaking in the middle of the MR number is not an option because the argument is used to build a link to the review. I frequently use `\sloppy` before the references, if that does not break anything else, but here I am looking for something that could be done to the entry.

What would you do to get a good linebreak here?

Comment: You would make it easier for us to give an answer if we had something to play with (an MWE). There are many things one could try, but general advice is a bit tricky.

Comment: Anything? If you are asking about the specific reference in your picture, please consider actually giving us that reference in an MWE. If you are only looking for general guidance please specify what exactly you are looking for at the moment it is not quite clear to me what an acceptable answer would be and what you would find not acceptable.